# Как сделать рассылку в Вконтакте с помощью python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, рассылка

Есть бот, на python, с POSTGRESQL и надо в него внедрить рассылку, кол-во пользователей, у этого бота, измеряется в тысячах, на данный момент в базе чуть больше 4к человек, надо как-то быстро всем им разослать сообщения, но как это сделать?
Вроде в вк есть ограничение по методу messages.send, что в user_ids нельзя указывать более 100 айдишников, использую асинхронную библиотеку saya, как бы не старался сделать код компактным и быстрым - ничего не получается, есть у вас идеи, как быстро разослать запросы по отправке сообщений 4-рём тысячам пользователей? Даже не обязательно, чтоб ваш код был написан на python-е, можете использовать любой язык, который вам удобен. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

У меня есть один метод.
Если у Вас есть база данных, то у меня один вопрос:
Каким образом она выглядит?

Например, моя - это файлы в одной из папок, в которой всё хранится для дальнейшего использования + там хранится информация о разрешениях о рассылке.

Мои файлы в базе названы с помощью `id` пользователей, с расширением `.dat`

Поэтому я получил имена всех файлов из папки с базой данных и сделал список под названием `ids`

После с помощью цикла `for` отправил это на каждый возможный `id`

```
import os

path = 'Data/Users/'
ids = os.listdir(path)

for id in ids:
    id = id.replace('.dat', '') #В моём случае я удалил текст с расширением в названии файла.
    send_msg(id, text)
```